# jaxWS "client" need a way to track raw xml requests and responses

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jaxb, jax-ws

I just got in to debug some jaxWS "client". I need a way to track raw xml requests and responses that process through. This is a legacy system so I don't want to do much code changes and break it further.Hence I'm looking for solution from configuration level. Note its very unlikely for me to change something from server end for debugging this.

Appreciate if anyone can shed a light on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using the jaxws impl built into the jdk, you can enable debug logging on the client using the system property "com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true" and on the server using "com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true" ([source](http://jax-ws.java.net/2.2.8/docs/ch06.html#message-logging)).

Comment: Hi Thank you for your reply. Still as I mentioned I don't have luxury to change anything on the server. Please let me know if I have a workaround without changing the server. I was able to track soap messages from TCPMON (got it redirected by editing wsdl prop from eclipse ) but need to proper way to log them on production server. cheers.

Comment: @Charith - i don't understand your comment.  you want to change the way the server behaves without changing anything on the server?

Comment: Apologies. I thought this is a setting I should change on server too. Apparently you've given both options.I shall check this and let you know. Thanks.